# Is * {position:relative} a bad idea?

Tags: css

Is this going to cause me untold grief if I stick it at the top of my stylesheet?

```
* {position:relative}
```

Comment: Title and question do not really match :-?

Comment: Well, if what I suggested was a good idea, I'd go ahead and deprecate static positioning.. Yes, they match IMO.

Comment: “Well, if what I suggested was a good idea, I'd go ahead and deprecate static positioning.” Good for you, but that’s not the same as `position: relative;` actually *being* deprecated (which would require the CSS spec to state that it’s deprecated, which it doesn’t).

Comment: Yes Paul, I'm sufficiently corrected. Thanks for debugging my question for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcards can cause performance issues when not used carefully. That would probably not be the case in your example, but it's a bad habit to develop.

But more importantly, it's rare that you can conclusively say you want any behavior to apply to *all* elements.

With relative positioning, you will at best achieve nothing and at worst create many headaches for yourself trying to troubleshoot things that would normally "just work".

Relative positioning definitely has its uses. Apply it when you need it.

Comment: id consider the floating issue the biggest problem. since asking this question, i've moved to floating just about everything in my DOM so i'm kind of shooting myself in the foot with this wildcard declaration hey?

Comment: Yes, I typically avoid wildcards altogether in CSS. It's rare that you can conclusively say you want any behavior to apply to ALL elements. Relative positioning definitely has its uses; just apply it when you need it via a specific CSS class or even a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 11):

> Is this going to cause me untold grief if I stick it at the top of my stylesheet?

Yes. You will not be able to work with absolutely positioned elements any more, for example - the absolute positioning will always be relative to the parent element, which is almost never the desired result.

I could imagine there are even more side-effects field of `z-index` settings.

Not a good idea IMO.

And no, `position: static` is *not* deprecated, after all, it is the default setting :)

Comment: Mm I try not to nest elements that are absolute relative to the viewport anyway.
I was hoping it would actually reduce potential z-index issues between firefox and ie.

Comment: @user278457 You won't even be able to position absolute to the parent's parent element any more that way. And correct me if I'm wrong, but I can't see how this will fix cross-browser z-index issues.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're getting at. I just don't think that way, or haven't needed to yet. I'd rather use two "left:10" than a "left:10" on the parent and a "left:20" on the child. I suppose it's a good idea to leave the option open if you're not feeling particularly disciplined one day.

Comment: @user278457 if it's for a small, personal home page, it's probably never going to be a problem, but anything that could grow in the future, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: "the absolute positioning will always be relative to the parent element, which is almost never the desired result"

This always is my desired result !

Comment: @user for *every single* element in your document?

Comment: I must agree with user1447420. I think most CSS is a hierarchy of nested boxes. We'd expect an inner box to be positioned relative to the parent box. This is the way grouping works in almost all graphical software, 3D, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad idea imho as it changes the default behaviour of elements without clear indication and it *will* have unforseen consequences.

If you really want to have most elements positioned relative, you might want to think about just making div and similar relative.

Comment: Much better idea. I think I'll experiment with sticking a div{position:relative} into my css reset.

Comment: @user278457 still a horrible idea. It may work for you now, but what if one day you need absolute positioning, or have to include an external widget.

Comment: I could give something an absolute position still. I just won't nest it in another div. I really don't see why you would nest something that is positioned relative to the viewport. You mean if I'm designing something that should be included on an external site, right?

Comment: @user278457 In my experience, it's not unusual to have absolutely positioned elements not relative to the body, but to a different element that has `position: relative`.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give the other side of the coin, I have used this setting quite a lot, and have found it useful. Main advance being the easiness of using positioning properties (top, left, right, bottom) without having to define relative positioning to parent all the time.

It's true that this setting will make it impossible to use absolute positioning in relation to anything else than the parent right above, but I find this to be a good thing. Because the first parent with 'position: relative' is visually de facto parent of any child with 'position:absolute', then it is only logical to make them direct children also in the HTML hierarchy.

In short `* {position:relative}` forces a convention that makes it easier to reason how positioning works.

**Caveat 1**: Event if the new convention simplifies things to new comers, it's different from what seasoned CSS developers are used. Prepare to face opposition if you start using this in big project with many frontend developers.

**Caveat 2**: Performance issue should be tested properly. I have tried turning this setting on and off on some big sites without noticing any difference, but no real tests with real numbers exist (to my knowledge).

Final note: First line in the second paragraph is not quite true. You can always overwrite wildcard definitions, setting `position: static` some mid level node, if you really need to.

Comment: This causes performance issues in Opera 12 (the last version using the Presto engine) so be careful. Setting z-index to any number fixes the problem though.

Comment: It also causes weird bugs in Firefox with table cells that have padding set in percents.

Answer (score 2):

**Answering title question:**

This is the current CSS 2.1 spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position

Accepted values include `static`, `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed` and `inherit`.

I'm not sure about CSS 3 (it's still work in progress) but they don't seem to mention `static`:

http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work#positioning

Whatever, I wouldn't really care yet :)

**Answering body question:**

The default is `static` so you'd be changing the property for every single item in the page. The best you can achieve is nothing. The worse is that you'll be probably creating weird side effects you won't even notice at first sight.

Also (this is pure speculation on my side), it can't be good for performance. I'm sure rendering engines are optimized for having a majority of static elements.

Comment: Good point. But the way they describe position relative implies that it is "relative" to some mysterious unnamed property that operates "as defined by the box model"